# JavaScript regex matching query parameters but not HTML entities

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get a regular expression that matches below:

Regular expression: `/(?:(?:https?):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*(?:&(?!lt]))*)/gi`

**Expectation**:

`https://a.com?a=b&c=d` => should match "https://a.com?a=b&c=d"

`https://a.com&lt;` => should match "https://a.com"

However, my regular expression is not quite working expected:

**Actual**:

is actually matching only :

`https://a.com?a=b&c=d` => matches "https://a.com?a=b&"

`https://a.com&lt;` => matches "https://a.com&"

Any idea how to get the regular expression working to match as per expectation?

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question? You seem to be just asking someone to solve the whole problem. Which part about regular expressions are you wondering about?

Also, I would recommend using a library such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/urijs instead of writing your own query paramter parser. This problem becomes quite easy that way, but if you write your own regular expression you will now have, as the saying goes, two problems instead of one.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't introduce a new lib, as of now.. that's why had to resort to a regular expression. But, I would like to use a open source library, instead of re-inventing a wheel :) Thanks for the NPM link though.. will check it out.

Comment: Try `https?:\/\/(?:(?![^&?\s]*&)\S*|[^&\s]*)`. Live demo https://regex101.com/r/eL0Apt/1

Answer (score 0):

This "works" (i.e. for your target input) but will likely need tweaking for the last part:

```
(?:https?):\/\/[\w-\.@#\/%?=~|!:,.;]*(?:&(?!lt)[\w=%]*)*
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/1bZ3Ie/2)

Comment: Think the part matching `&x=y` needs to repeat, otherwise subsequent params will not be matched. So needs a `*` instead of `?` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If your regex is supposed to validate a URL then it shouldn't allow pipes or semi-colons etc. If it's a matter of matching so this should do the job:

```
https?:\/\/(?:(?![^&?\s]*&)\S*|[^&\s]*)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/eL0Apt/1)

This ensures that there shouldn't be a `&` if no `?` is found earlier.

Breakdown:

- `https?:\/\/` Match a protocol preceding `://`
- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

  - `(?![^&?\s]*&)` If no `&` happens after `?`
  - `\S*` Match any non-whitespace character
  - `|` Or
  - `[^&\s]*` Anything up to `&`
- `)` End of non-capturing group